# How to use linq to map xml to a class?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Say my xml looks like:

```
<post>
<title>this is a title</title>
<date>2013/06/03</date>
<message>this is a message here</message>
</post>
```

And I have a class like:

```
public class Post
{
  public string Title {get;set;}
  public string Message {get;set;}
  public DateTime Date {get;set;}
}
```

I have an xml document object that has the xml.

Now sure how to use linq to populate this.  Does linq handle nulls or bad xml (like say the 'message' node is missing?).

Comment: Have you considered using the [XmlSeriliazer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for that:

```
var post = new Post()
           {
               Title = (string)doc.Root.Element("title"),
               Date = (DateTime)doc.Root.Element("date"),
               Message = (string)doc.Root.Element("message")
           }
```

And to answer your additional questions:

> Does linq handle nulls or bad xml (like say the 'message' node is
>   missing?).

It depends how you describe *bad xml*! `XDocument` will throw an exception if the input is not a proper XML file. So your input has to be correct XML file.  However, missing `message` tag won't be a problem here. `(string)doc.Root.Element("message")` will return `null` if there is no `message` element under the `doc.Root` element.

However, it will crash if the `date` element is missing. That's because `null` cannot be assigned to `DateTime` property.

Comment: thanks, so how can I guard against it crashing b/c of a date?  can I use DateTime.Parse ?

Comment: Simple fix is to use nullable datetime.  `DateTime?`

Answer (score 0):

If you can fix the style of the XML I'd deserialize it instead

```
private static string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<Post>
    <Title>this is a title</Title>
    <ProxyDateTime>2013/06/03</ProxyDateTime>
    <Message>this is a message here</Message>
</Post>";

public class Post
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string ProxyDateTime
    {
        get { return Date.Date.ToString(); }
        set { Date = DateTime.Parse(value); }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
            new [] {"Title: " + Title, "Date: " + Date, "Message: " + Message});
    }
}
```

Sample usage

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Post));
var post = (Post)serializer
    .Deserialize(new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml)));
Console.WriteLine(post);
```

This allows you to handle nulls in a strongly typed manner. I've used LINQ to XML to do this in the past. It works, but can get very cumbersome with large classes. This way your code is much more extendable.